# Cover screws for panel do not fit

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I got a 125Amp panel (Siemens) for installation, and found that the cover screws included did not fit. I later found that my sheet metal screws, fit perfectly. Are there any NEC guidelines against this?[image: actual screw]
[image: screwed in sheet screws.]

Comment: is the panel correctly assembled?

Comment: Yeah, the problem I had was that the panel cover was really loose when I screwed it in. (*the original screws)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That self tapping screw is a code violation and I know several inspectors that will fail a home owner and an electrician for not using load center cover screws.

The load center screws have a larger head and almost always have a #2 square / slotted head , I got hammered many years ago and even stock several different brands as they are different.

Many of these screws are self forming NOT self tapping. Code specified self forming 2 threads in contact, yes self forming are tough to put in the first time but believe me that is a red flag for inspectors in my area.

I believe 1 brand has corse threads but it is a large head with a slotted / #2 square drive and is ok because it is according to the mfg directions. Self tappers do not.

Comment: The OP probably ruined the hole with the self tapping screws.

Comment: What are they citing for the failures? 250.8(A) (with the screw as a system or supply-side bonding jumper between cabinet and front)? Or is this more of a listing/instructions issue?

Comment: 110.2 the mfg listed equipment has load center cover screws not self tappers. As I said some mfg’s do have corse screws but they still have the oversized heads. 250.8 is for grounding and bonding it specifies 2 threads or secured with a nut. 314.25 covers and canopies where nonmetallic or metal covers and plates , machine screw matching cover size , I think there is another reference to #6, #8 & #10 screws 32 pitch but I may be combining a cover plate grounding requirement.  So there are several references with the mfg listed assembly being first.

Comment: @EdBeal -- yeah, makes sense that it'd get written up as a 110.2, given that a too long or too pointy screw can mess up wire insulation